# Is there a way to add constraints to UserMedia using Tone.js?

Tags: web-audio-api, getusermedia, mediadevices, tone.js

On MediaDevices: getUserMedia() method it's possible to add a constraints parameter:

getUserMedia(constraints)

Is it possible to do the same with Tone.js UserMedia?, if so, how?

const mic = new Tone.UserMedia().connect(recorder);

Where would I add the constraints parameter?